# Windows Installer (MSI 5.0) fails with ERROR 1939 during "MsiConfigureServices" action

Tags: windows-services, windows-installer

When trying to install a setup package using the new MSI 5.0 features of Windows Service Configuration (using Tables: MsiServiceConfig / MsiServiceConfigFailureActions)
the service config fails and results in a rollback.

The service itself is installed along with the same package under "LocalSystem" account.
Regarding MSDN, these feature does have some limitations, but I am not sure if they are applicable here:

> "The services configuration feature of the Windows Installer cannot configure network service accounts, install shared service host (svchost) processes, or restart services stopped as part of the installation"
>   (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408113(v=vs.85).aspx )

I have tried this with several variations on the failure actions count and type.
Using SC_ACTION_NONE or SC_ACTION_RUN_COMMAND actions indeed work and lead to a successful install.

Can you tell, why SC_ACTION_RESTART or SC_ACTION_REBOOT does not work fine?

**MSI Log File excerpt:**

```
Action 08:21:51: InstallServices. Installing new services
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:51:828]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=5,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=1300000)
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:51:859]: Executing op: ServiceInstall(Name=PCSProxy,DisplayName=Protection Communication System Proxy,ImagePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Protection Communication System\Pcs.Proxy.Service.exe",ServiceType=16,StartType=2,ErrorControl=32769,,Dependencies=[~],,,Password=**********,Description=Provides limited write access to the PPS,,)
InstallServices: Service: 
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:218]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=MsiConfigureServices,,)
Action 08:21:52: MsiConfigureServices. 
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:280]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=1,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=1300000)
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:280]: Executing op: ServiceConfigure(,Name=PCSProxy,Event=1,ConfigType=4,Argument=1)
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:280]: Changing configuration of service PCSProxy.
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:280]: Changed configuration of service PCSProxy with ConfigType SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS_FLAG
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:358]: Done changing configuration of service PCSProxy
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:358]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=1,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=1300000)
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:358]: Executing op: ServiceConfigureFailureAction(,Name=PCSProxy,Event=1,ResetPeriod=259200,RebootMessage=Rebooting the system,Command=cmd.exe,Actions=1[~]2[~]3,DelayActions=60000[~]60000[~]60000)
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:374]: Changing configuration of failure action for service PCSProxy.
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:374]: Error: 5. Failed to change current configuration of failure action for service PCSProxy
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:21:52:374]: Failed to change configuration of failure action for service PCSProxy
Error 1939. Service 'Protection Communication System Proxy' (PCSProxy) could not be configured.  This could be a problem with the package or your permissions. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to configure system services.
MSI (s) (78:74) [08:22:04:791]: Product: Protection Communication System -- Error 1939. Service 'Protection Communication System Proxy' (PCSProxy) could not be configured.  This could be a problem with the package or your permissions. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to configure system services.

Action ended 08:22:04: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

[...]

Property(C): VersionNT = 602
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 500
Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(C): VersionNT64 = 602
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 9200
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 3
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 1031
Property(C): ComputerName = WIN-D4AOTTU5CRV
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1031
Property(C): Time = 07:33:17
Property(C): Date = 18.04.2013
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.17929
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.2.9200.16384
```